# Jawbone UP Android OAuth redirect_uri: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, authentication, webview, oauth-2.0, jawbone

Integrating an Android fitness app with Jawbone UP REST API.

I'm not overly familiar with OAuth so forgive me if my question is basic.

Jawbone's documentation states that the redirect_uri can be specified as:

up-platform://redirect

This is based on the following SDK:

https://github.com/Jawbone/UPPlatform_Android_SDK

From that link the documentation states:

"Obtain Your OAuth Credentials

Sign into the Jawbone UP Developer Portal using your Jawbone UP account. If you do not have an account you can create one by going to jawbone.com/start/signup. Register your organization by pressing "Manage Account". Follow the instructions to create a new app and get your OAuth Client ID and App Secret keys that you will use to authenticate with the UP Platform.
Specify your custom redirect URI in the "OAuth Redirect URI" field or use the default value up-platform://redirect. Note that for Android SDK this url is redundant, we will never leave the app and thus won't need to be redirected to it. But the OAuth specification calls for it. Also, this framework is also used by Jawbone for web based OAuth authentication so we leave it here. Suffice to say whatever non-null uri is entered here should be the same used in app."

When running in Android the sdk kicks you out to a webview at which point you login with your Jawbone account

I "seem" to successfully login but immediately after I Accept the permissions I receive the following:

"Webpage not available"

The webpage at up-platform://redirect?(bunch of seemingly encoded text) coule not be loaded because:

net:ERROR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

I'd appreciate any direction here.  I'm not sure where to begin to look.

Thanks